# Why is it allowed to pass the parameter value by reference with the duplicated sign &?

Tags: rust

Why is it allowed to pass the parameter value by reference with the duplicated sign `&` ?

```
fn by_ref(v: &u64) -> u64 {
    v + 1
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", by_ref(&&&1));
}
```

Comment: See [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html#deref-and-method-calls).

Comment: Exactly what I need!

Comment: @ljedrz: The pun is not lost on me.